# Creating a personnalized PCA (not using variance as optimization criteria)

Tags: pca

I have a simple question (I hope I can explain it clear enough). 
I want to train and apply a PCA to a set of data (I want to have an orthogonal basis in a low dimension subspace with unitary vectors), but the criteria that I want to maximize for the projected axes is not the variance of the data.

I was wondering if using the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix other than the covariance matrix still gives a correct and usable basis.

For example: Let's say I have a symmetric matrix that represents a certain distance on each dimension computed over my data. Does the first eigen-vector of that matrix represent an axis that maximizes that distance ? 
And could the whole set of eigenvectors be used as basis ?

Sorry if the question is silly, but any response will be of big help. Thanks !

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you don't want to maximize the variance, what is it exactly that you're trying to do? Is it a form of [multidimensional scaling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)?

Comment: The question is not silly, only it is stingily asked. Explain by a concrete example.

Comment: @Dougal That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks !!